# Que diferencia hay entre un import con parentesis y sin ellos

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con meteor y react, en el archivo main.js importo dos clases de diferentes sitios por ejemplo

```
import {Players} from './../imports/api/players';
import TitleBar  from './../imports/ui/TitleBar';
```

Que diferencia hay entre uno y otro o a que se deben los parentesis dentro de uno y en el otro no o de que depende, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el primer caso estas importando sólo el miembro `Players` y asignándolo a la variable `Players`.

En el segundo caso estas importando todo el módulo bajo la variable `TitleBar`.

La sintaxis completa puedes verla en [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)

Comment: Te agradezco por la informacion Carlos, saludos! Me quedo claro al fin.